# JavaScript Why does string interpolation for single $ and double $$ have same result in replace function?

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace some code in js using template literals and came across this anomaly. Could someone explain why the below replacement produces the same output.
I've tested it in Chrome(ver.92.0.4515.107) and FireFox too with the same result in the console.
Is there something more to template literals.

```js
console.log("word".replace("word", `${"$$test"}`));
//outputs : $test

console.log("word".replace("word", `${"$test"}`));
//outputs : $test

console.log(`${"$$test"}`) // direct console outputs the right value
//$$test
```

Comment: I now changed my code to    "word".replace("word", `${"$$test"}`.replaceAll("$$","$$$$$"));  which kind of gives the required result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with template literals. You'll see the same result if you use ordinary strings. It's because of the way the `.replace()` method performs its substitution.

`$` has special meaning in the replacement string. The most common use is to interpolate a capture group when replacing with a regular expression, but the special processing is done even when replacing a fixed string.

`$$` is the way you escape the `$` so that it inserts a `$`, which is why `$$test` puts `$test` in the replacement.

`$test` does the same thing because `$t` has no special meaning, so it's treated literally.

Comment: I understand now. Was not aware that $ is treated differently. Alsmost spent an hour trying to figure out if my code was sending wrong values in a loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$` has a special meaning in the replacement string. The replacement string uses ***$n*** to refer to the ***nth*** captured group, and `$$` is the specific way to produce a single dollar symbol.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 1):

It's the replacement string (by design). [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). The (special replacement) pattern `$$` is replaced by `$`

Comment: So its the replace function doing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's facing this issue in the future, below is a possible solution.
Used replacer function and regex to avoid pattern matching replacement. Although an escape character of some sort would do the job better.

```
var result = "word".replace("word",
          `${"$$test$$$"}`
            .replaceAll(/(?<=\$)[\$]+/g, x => "$".repeat(x.length * 2)));
console.log(result);

//example
console.log("<span id='tabid' [tabpage=$$navliID]></span>".replace("[tabpage=$$navliID]", `tabpage='${"$$navli$$$"}'`.replaceAll(/(?<=\$)[\$]+/g, x => "$".repeat(x.length * 2))));
```